# How can I change the add to cart button text to an icon in Woocommerce? (Variable Products)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, elementor

so I have been struggling on this problem.

I wanna change the variable add to cart Button to an Icon. This is what my code does

[image: Variable add to cart button]

And what I wanna achieve:

[image]

I am using Elementor and the products are in a slider from Ultimate Addons for Elementor, which I customized for my needs. Link of the doc (https://ultimateelementor.com/docs/filters-actions-for-woocommerce-products)

```
function price_after( $product_id, $settings ) {
global $product;
$sprache = $product->get_attribute('sprache');
if( ! empty( $sprache ) ){
    
    woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart();

    //$link['url'] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
    /*$link['label'] = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Warenkorb', 'woocommerce' ) );*/
} else {
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        echo '<div class="add_to_cart_wishlist">'; 
        echo "<button class='button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart' href='https://[siteurl]/?add-to-cart=".$product_id."'data-product_id='".$product_id."'>". file_get_contents('[siteurl]/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/cart-1-1-1.svg')."</button>";
        echo do_shortcode("[ti_wishlists_addtowishlist]");
        echo "</div>";
    } }} add_action('uael_woo_products_price_after', 'price_after', 10, 2);
```

And this is what I use to change the text of the add to cart button

```
function filter_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text( $add_to_cart_text, $product ) {

        $add_to_cart_text = 'Test';

    return $add_to_cart_text;
}

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'filter_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'filter_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
```

I even deleted the esc_html in the template folder of woocommerce...
[image]

Now I dont know to do else, I need your help!!!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can follow this link it's useful for you: https://codeastrology.com/change-woocommerce-add-to-cart-text/

Comment: Hey Savan, thanks for your answer I now made the text remove with php and replaced it with jquery. Not the state of the art but it does the job